# Are there any Vor-families that don't have a Countship?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

In the Vorkosigan books, the elite families all have Vor prefixes to their names (Vorbarra, Vorsoisson, Vorpatril, Vorkosigan, Vorinnis, etc).  All of the 60 Countships are held by Vor families, but it's never been quite clear to me whether all the Vor-families have a Countship; is there a Count Vorvayne that we never see, or are there some families that are in the Vor elite who currently have no Countship?

Comment: No, Vorbarra explicitly has a Courtside and a district as I recall - as Count Vorbarra Gregor has one vote in the Council

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was thinking.  Now that you mention it, It's even explicitly mentioned when Miles is on trial and Gregor votes in order as Count Vorbarra instead of waiting to vote last as Emperor.